# How to combine template and outchannel together in rsyslog.conf?

Tags: syslog, rsyslog

i am try to play with rsyslog configuration.
To my knowledge

To enable log rotation: we should do something below:

```
$outchannel log_rotation,/var/log/syslog.log, 1048576 ,/usr/bin/rotate.sh
*.* :omfile:$log_rotation
```

And to tabulate syslog with a template : we should do something like this:

```
$template CSVData, "%timereported:::date-rfc3339%,\
                    %hostname%,\
                    %syslogfacility-text%,\
                    %syslogpriority-text%,\
                    %app-name:::csv%,\
                    %msg:::drop-last-lf,csv%\n"
  
 *.* /var/log/syslog.log;CSVData
```

May i know  how to combine these two together? My intention is to tabulate a syslog with my template and have it rotate when the log is exceed 1MB.

At first i thought of

```
$outchannel log_rotation,/var/log/syslog.log;CSVData, 1048576 ,/usr/bin/rotate.sh
*.* :omfile:$log_rotation
```

But it not working, it just generate file known as `syslog.log;CSVData`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some googling around , i just aware i can use

```
$ActionFileDefaultTemplate CSVData
```

Do let me know if you have better solutions